# Sorting on fields containing Numbers as strings

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I am trying to sort results in elastic search based on a field named "segmentNumber" that has numbers stored as strings i.e `("1", "2", "10", "14")`. I need to write an ES query to get results in sorted ascending order and descending as shown below.

**Ascending order:**

```
{segmentNumber: "1"},

{segmentNumber: "2"},

{segmentNumber: "10"},

{segmentNumber: "14"},
```

**Descending Order:**

```
{segmentNumber: "14"},

{segmentNumber: "10"},

{segmentNumber: "2"},

{segmentNumber: "1"},
```

I am using a sort script as shown below to achieve this, but it **doesn't work** for me

```
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "script": "try { Integer.parseInt(doc[\"segmentNumber.keyword\"].value); } catch(Exception e){ return Integer.MAX_VALUE;}",
        "type": "number",
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Could anyone please suggest me how to achieve this functionality ? Thanks!

Comment: can you add your index mapping.

Comment: Hi @SagarPatel, here is the index mapping below

       







































"segmentNumber" : {
          "type" : "short",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "ngram" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "ngram_tokenizer_analyzer"
            }
          }
        },